# Dynamically add another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually my code is very complex but for simplicity i am putting this example:

I have two components in react:

Component_A:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class Component_A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>Component A</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Component_A;
```

Component_B:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class Component_B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

export default Component_B;
```

App file:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Component_B from './Component_B';

 class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Component_A />
                <Component_B />
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Index file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Now After page renders, and i will get call from server, at that time I want to **append** Component_A into Component_B. Is there any solution for that?

Most of you can see this ridiculous and will advice to do it with state facility of react. but as i have written above this is very complex project. so It will be very easy for us if we can do it with **append**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution entirely depends on the architecture of the project. You can conditionally render components at any point. If I understood you correctly you can do it like this:

```
//Component_A:
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class Component_A extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>Component A</div>
      );
  }
}

export default Component_A;


//Component_B:
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class Component_B extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Component_B;

//app

import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Component_A from './Component_A';
import Component_B from './Component_B';

class App extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    api.fetchData().then(data => {
      this.setState({data});
    })
  }

 render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <Component_B/>
          {this.state.data && <Component_A />}
        </Component_B>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Or you can move `Component_A` to the `Component_B`:

```
//Component_A:
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class Component_A extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>Component A</div>
      );
  }
}

export default Component_A;


//Component_B:
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Component_A from './Component_A';

class Component_B extends React.Component {
  render(){
    if (!this.props.data) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Component_B />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Component_B;

//app

import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Component_B from './Component_B';

class App extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    api.fetchData().then(data => {
      this.setState({data});
    })
  }

 render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <Component_B data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

You can always return `null` from component to hide its html

```
class Component_A extends React.Component {
  render(){
    if (!this.props.visible) return null;
    return (
      <div>Component A</div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but i want to append already mounted Component_A with it's state and props

Comment: Thanks buddy, by your method, our goal had implemented successfully. And sorry that i am not able to vote you as i have less than 15 points.